# Не отображается header в Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, microsoft-edge

```css
header {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #2b1411;
    height: 67px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
}

header nav {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    
    padding: 0 30px;
}

header nav > a {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fffccc;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

header .photo_header {
    margin-left: 70px;
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/T8A8ReS.jpg") no-repeat center;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 0 1000px 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 -300px;
}
```

```html
<header>
            <div class="photo_header"></div>
            <nav>
                    <a href="#home">HOME</a>
                    <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                    <a href="#explore">EXPLORE</a>
                    <a href="#team">TEAM</a>
                    <a href="#contacts">CONTACT</a>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Не отображается хедер сайта в браузере Microsoft Edge. Во всех остальных браузерах отображается.

Comment: В хроме логотипа не видно и часть меню прячется за правый край экрана. https://i.gyazo.com/a0fdfde6f4f297927b9555253a91f0f2.png Как должно выглядеть?

Comment: это я просто набросок когда залил. Суть в том, что в хроме и остальных браузерах хедер отображается(пусть даже такой). А в Edge он просто игнорируется браузером, хотя в коде его видно.

Comment: Возникает гипотеза, что эйдж усиливает недостатки существующего кода. Будет легче помочь, если эту гипотезу исключить. Замените, пожалуйста, код на рабочий. Чтобы он отлично выглядел во всех браузерах и игнорировался эйджем.

Comment: Тут вопрос не стоит о виде, а о видимости. Даже такой хедер во всех браузерах нормально отображается, а в edge его попросту нет

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день!
Проверил ваш код в браузере Edge 25.1
Отображается аналогично Chrome.
Я считаю то, что у вас первая проблема может крыться в логотипе.
У вас логотип подгружается размером 4000х800рх, а текже прописаны весьма странные отступы.

```
padding: 0 1000px 0 0;
margin: 0 0 0 -300px;
```

Попробуйте для начала использовать заранее смасштабированный логотип и уберите эти отступы.